# regarding Facebook / JSON integration

Tags: php, json, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to include Facebook on a page of my website using my CSS styling. I'm VERY new to PHP and I'm having a lot of trouble getting my code to return any results.

I'm including my code below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Facebook display
*/
?>
<div class="wrapper">
<aside id="pageSidebar">
</aside>
<section id="pageContent">
<?php
$page_id = 'MY PAGE';
$access_token = 'ACCESS TOKEN GOES HERE';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . '/posts?access_token=' . $access_token);
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
$posts .= '<div><a href="' . $post->link .'">' . $post->story . '</a></div>';
$posts .= '<div><a href="'. $post->link .'">' . $post->message . '</a></div>';
$posts .= '<div>' . $post->description . '</div>';
$posts .= '<br />';
}
?>
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I then included the following on the page that is supposed to display the Facebook posts

```
[php]
<?php include 'filename.php'; ?>
[/php]
```

I've activated the php shortcode in Wordpress and  I set allow_url_fopen = On in my php.ini file. However Nothing. I can't get the posts to display. I have tested the access token and page id. These are fine. Page is public. Running out of ideas and, honestly, out of my depth here.

Comment: Are you getting results from doing a var_dump($json_object); ?

Comment: No. However it looks like the include command isn't loading the PHP in the first place. At least my console isn't showing me any communication between the PHP file and the page that is calling it.

Comment: Ok, so I spent some more time researching how to actually debug a PHP script. var_dump($json_object); returns bool(false)

Comment: Oh. LOL! Somehow my access token got overwritten with garbage data. One sec...

Comment: Ok, now the var_dump is returning the correct results for $json_object

Comment: Alright, so the php is pushing the data into something resembling a recognizable form but it's still not pushing through to the page where I included it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a lot of this was down to my ignorance of how to integrate PHP into HTML. I was able to do the following:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Facebook display
*/
?>
<div>
<?php
$page_id = 'PageID';
$access_token = 'AccessToken';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/PageID/posts?access_token=AccessToken');
//Interpret data 
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
$posts .= '<div><h4><a href="' . $post->link .'"><img style="float: left;" height ="100" src="' . $post->picture . '" /></a>';
$posts .= '<a href="'. $post->link .'">' . $post->message . '</a></h4>';
$posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
$posts .= '<hr />';
}
echo ($posts);
?>  
</div>
```

to produce my PHP file.

From there I made sure my settings were correct in PHP.ini - allow_url_fopen = On being the important one.

Finally I inserted the following code onto the destination page:

```
<table id="var">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<script>
$("#var").load("php url");
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this provided me with the styling I was looking for - at a basic level. I still am working on including like numbers and threaded comments but that's another issue altogether.

At least, at the core, I solved my initial problem, which was to push a facebook JSON feed to my destination page with the appropriate CSS applied.